# Save AJAX request URL to a variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm making a GET request to my API

```
$.get('www.test.com/api.php', {
  action: 'getItems',
  name: settings.name,
  id:  settings.id
}, function(data){}
```

How can I save the AJAX request url (`www.test.com/api.php?action=getItems&name=names&id=3`) in to a variable?

Comment: Why do you want to make variable for url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var url = 'www.test.com/api.php';
$.get(url, {action: 'getItems', name: settings.name,id:  settings.id},function(data){}
```